# AWS S3 Object delete from console deletes versions too

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have recently enabled **object versioning** on our AWS S3 Bucket. My understanding was that if I enable versioning on a bucket the object will not be deleted but a delete marker will be created with some `VersionId`. The idea is to not loose any data whatsoever. When tried deleting from console after enabling versioning on Bucket the object and all its versions were deleted. But when using AWS SDK for NodeJS `deleteObject` method it returned me `DeleteMarker` and `VersionId` and I was able to restore the object. Can we get the same behaviour from console?

Answer (score 3):

Do not worry -- the previous versions were *not* deleted.

When viewing a Versioned bucket using the Amazon S3 management console, there is a **Versions** control that allows you to select `Hide` or `Show`.

When deleting an object in the default view, the object will appear to have been deleted. However, if you select `Versions: Show`, then the previous version(s) and the Delete Marker will appear.

This is because the default view only shows the 'latest version' of the object. If an object is deleted in this view, a Delete Marker is added as the latest version, which makes it look like the object is gone. Changing to `Versions: Show` will reveal the Delete Marker and the prior version(s).

Comment: Yes you are right, if I delete an object while viewing the versions disabled (default) view, it creates a delete marker and hides the object which can be seen by switching to the version enabled view but If someone deletes and object **while viewing versions and the object has only one version then it deletes the whole object**. Thanks for the help @John :)

Comment: Could you please add this detail to answer (If you agree with the comment) so that I mark this accepted. Thanks.